# Xcode and / or OSX, how can I setup SHIFT + INSERT as shortcut key for paste?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm use to windows development and use shift + insert with my day job, all day, it's an old short cut available since early windows versions.

Can I setup this short cut for using in xcode and / or osx ?

I had a look in `system preference` `keyboard` but it wouldn't accept it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open preferences in xCode and select "Key Bindings".

Comment: I don't really want to loose existing key strokes but add additional ones, that looks like it will change them.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question, found an answer:

There is a program called BetterTouchTool for osx that allows you to re-map keys, so you can map cmd+v to shift+insert and both will work as paste.

It does cost, but is pretty reasonable.

https://www.boastr.net/

--edit--
https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/201_keyboard_shortcuts.html
[image]

Comment: Can you please give some specific steps?  I have BTT and tried this but I didn't see any insert key emulation.

Comment: Edited for more info.